# Complex Integration and Uniform continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ be a closed rectangle and for $\epsilon>0$, let $R_{\epsilon}$ be the rectangle $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]\times [c+\epsilon, d-\epsilon]$.

Consider this situation in $\mathbb{C}$, and $f$ a continuous function on $R$. I didn't understand why the uniform continuity of $f$ implies the convergence of complex integration $$\int_{\partial R_{\epsilon}} f(z)dz\rightarrow  \int_{\partial R} f(z)dz\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,as  \,\,\,\, \epsilon\rightarrow 0.$$

Can you help me to understand last implication?

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it for circles instead. The idea is the same, but there will be a little less writing. You should be able to adapt the procedure to rectangles.

Let $D_r = \{ |z| = r \}$ and assume that $f$ is continuous on $\bar D_r$. Then (for $s \le r$):

\begin{align}
\left| \int_{\partial D_r} f(z)\,dz  - \int_{\partial D_s} f(z)\,dz \right| &=
\left| \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{it}) re^{it}\,dt - \int_0^{2\pi} f(se^{it}) se^{it}\,dt \right|\\
&\le \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{it})r-f(se^{it})s|\,dt \\
&\le \int_0^{2\pi}\big( |f(re^{it})r-f(se^{it})r| + |(s-r)f(se^{it})| \big)\,dt \\ 
&\le 2\pi r \max_{0\le t \le s} |f(re^{it})-f(se^{it})| + 2\pi |s-r| \max_t |f(se^{it})| \\
&\le 2\pi r \max_{0\le t \le s} |f(re^{it})-f(se^{it})| + 2\pi |s-r| \max_{z \in \bar D_r} |f(z)|.
\end{align}

As $s \nearrow r$, the first term tends to $0$ by uniform continuity of $f$, and the second term tends to $0$ since $f$ is bounded on $\bar D_r$.